# MFC Windows Menu, customizing

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I can't find where in MFC the individual View/Document/Frame names are added to the "Window" menu.

CMDIFrameWndEx::GetWindowMenuPopup searches the top level Menu for ID_'s related to the "Windows" menu. and returns this sub menu. But it doesn't modify anything.

I guess I could override this function to return my own HMENU that I handle directly. But I really, would like to know which function in MFC adds the items to this "Window" menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu is updated in the `CFrameWnd::OnUpdateFrameMenu`. This was an undocumented method, but that [changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc665913.aspx) when CFrameWndEx was added to MFC.

This might also be of interest: [How to Use Multiple Menus in MFC App That Uses GetDefaultMenu](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145857).

Comment: I still couldn't find the function in MFC that adds the document titles to the Windows menu. OnUpdateFrameMenu calls SetMenu() which i couldn't find source for.
However, using GetDefaultMenu() solved the bugs I was having, thanks!